# tensorflow CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN error

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I downloaded CUDA Toolkit 8.0 GA2, cuDNN v6.0 for CUDA 8 and tensorflow 1.4. I have an Nvidia 740M graphics chip. I tried running this code to test tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

This is what it returns:

```
2017-11-09 16:25:42.999638: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compil
ed to use: AVX AVX2
2017-11-09 16:25:43.007712: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
2017-11-09 16:25:43.010457: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-06398IN
2017-11-09 16:25:43.010576: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: DESKTOP-06398IN
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

What does the error CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN mean? How do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Did you validate the CUDA install on your laptop?  Have you made sure to properly enable the GPU apps you want to run with optimus profiles?

Comment: have you installed GPU enabled tensorflow or build with GPU support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the graphics driver fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. Spent a few hours looking for an answer, changing CUDA and CUDNN versions, and this was what I was missing.